# "Application opened for the first time" warning after every reboot

Tags: macos, applications, filesystem, dialog

I have a problem with Lion 10.7.5.: the system does not remember that I already opened applications before. After every reboot, every time I open an application it displays the warning as if it's the first time I'm opening it. After various tests I think the culprit is lsregister. Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Or as an alternative, anyone knows if there is a plist file that can be edited manually to tell the system that the application has already been opened?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a permissions error somewhere. Run Disk Utility (from the /Applications/Utilities folder), select your boot drive and click on the "Repair Disk Permissions" button. I usually keep pressing the buttons until there are no errors left. Reboot and try running one of your problem apps. It may warn you again, but after that it should remember that you have run it before.

Good Luck.

Comment: Permission repaired, but unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes happens if the app was installed by another user on your system. If thats the case try to switch ownership of the file.

Found a similar post with a solution https://superuser.com/questions/38658/how-to-suppress-repetition-of-warnings-that-an-application-was-downloaded-from-t

Comment: I'm the only user on this system, but just to be sure, where can I see the owner of the application?

Comment: Open Terminal in /Applications/Utilities and type "ls -l /Applications". That show all files in the applications dir. You could do "ls -l /Applications | grep iTunes".
That shows the iTunes app

Comment: You were right, the applications that give me problems have different owners or groups than the other ones. How can I change them to admin? The link you gave me only explain the command for quarantine flags, but those flags are used for a different kind of warning (com.apple.quarantine does not exist in my system).

Comment: You were right, it didn't help. Well, that's another possibility discarded.

Comment: @Lauri That command only changes owner/group on the top level of the app. It's really a folder. You should use "sudo chown -R user:group folder"

Comment: It would be worth a try to make a copy of your Application and then run the command "sudo chmod -R username:admin /Applications/app-name"

Comment: If I launch your command I receive this error "chmod: Invalid file mode: username:admin". I also tried putting my username instead of "username" but the error is the same.

Comment: Sorry. Not chmod but chown. Chmod changes file permissions while chown changes owner and group. And yes replace username with your own

Answer (score 1):

for me it helped to move the app from homedir to applications

Comment: Helped me too. Please check if maybe the File is still in Downloads or sth like that

Answer (score 0):

I believe this format is still correct for Lion - open a new shell in Terminal (or ssh in) and run: `defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool false`

Comment: The option is in LaunchServices.plist but unfortunately the dialog still pops up after reboot. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It normally only removes the warnings shown when opening files with a quarantine attribute, but not the ones shown when opening applications for the first time.